# showing contacts by filtering account_type column from RawContacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

Im getting showing contacts on a `RecyclerView`  and below code retrieve contacts

```
 Uri Contact_URI=ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;


            return  new CursorLoader(getActivity(),Contact_URI,null,null,null,Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                    >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+ "ASC");
```

but some contacts are being shown multiple times so I decided to filter Contacts on `account_type` column. Below code filter based on `account_type`

```
if(list.getString(list.getColumnIndex("account_type")).equals("Local Phone Account") || list.getString(list.getColumnIndex("account_type")).equals("SIM Account") ) {

            textView.setText(list.getString(list.getColumnIndex(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                    >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            number.setText(list.getString(list.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
        number.setText(list.getString(list.getColumnIndex("account_type")));

        }
```

Problem is values of `account_type` for sim and phone contacts varies from device to device. In `Samsung GT-l9082` gives values for sim "Sim Account" and for Phone "Local Phone Account" but When I tested it on `Galaxy J5` it shows different values against `account_type` for sim and phone contacts.I want to show only Sim and Phone Contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way to go.

`CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` is a table of **all the phones** in the Contacts DB, not contacts.
So even if you filter to just one account, if a contact contains more then one phone, it'll appear twice in your list.

If you want to display only one row per contact, but you still need to display a phone in your main list, you can't use the `CursorLoader` paradigm (which actually sucks and I wouldn't use it anyway).

Instead run a simple query for all the items in the `Phones.CONTENT_URI` table, and create a `HashMap` from `CONTACT_ID` to a list of `NUMBER`s, and then display one row per item in the map, and you'll get access to that contact's list of phones as well for display.

```
Map<String, List<String>> contacts = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

String[] projection = { Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };
Cursor cur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    String data = cur.getString(2); // the actual info, e.g. +1-212-555-1234

    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + ", " + data);

    // add info to existing list if this contact-id was already found, or create a new list in case it's new
    String key = id + " - " + name;
    List<String> infos;
    if (contacts.containsKey(key)) {
        infos = contacts.get(key);
    } else {
        infos = new ArrayList<String>();
        contacts.put(key, infos);
    }
    infos.add(data);
}

// now you can iterate over the 'contacts' map to display all contacts
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I also thought it to filter Contacts but `CursorLoader` returns a `Cursor` and `CursorLoader.query()` runs on NON-UI thread. so that doesn't matters. Although, I agree on using HashMaps. I am accepting it as Answer

Comment: You can run the query and build the HashMap on a non-UI thread yourself (using a Thread), and then pass the HashMap to an adapter to display the data on screen

Comment: I have fetched only Phone numbers directly  querying `ContactsContract.Data` and filter on `Data.MIMTYPE=Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE `. it only gives me phone numbers of contacts whether belongs to SIM or  Phone or any Email  Account

Comment: the query you've mentioned on `ContactsContract.Data` is the same as simply querying on `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` the `Phone` table adds the mimetype selection for you.

Comment: yeah I know but now prob is if i include these column in projection `Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.LOOKUP_KEY,Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,Phone.NUMBER` it gives me only phone numbers saved in contacts but if include additional column like `Phone.Data_Version` in that projection it showing duplicates as `Whatsapp` also has mimetype phone.  I think it should show duplicates  without `Phone.Data_Version` column coz whatsapp contact also saving number with phone mimetype

Comment: I don't think changing projection can affect the selection of the query, but either way, use the HashMap solution, where the key is CONTACT_ID (Long instead of String) and you shouldn't have any duplicates whatsoever

Comment: i got the problem, When without Data VERSION column it only returns phone numbers with phone mimetype but when with Data Version Column as every data row for different account type with same phone numbers (whatsapp , phone/sim) have different column value of Data_Version thats why it is showing whatsapp phone and phone/sim phone mimetype separately ,hence Im watching duplicates on changing projection